# Moving text with ViewPager.PageTransformer - failed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-pagetransformer

I have a generic fragment with 2 textview inside:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/background_image"/>    

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/IntroTitle"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/description"
            style="@style/IntroDescription"
            android:text="Description"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout is used by IntroFragment and this class is instanciated 5 times in my ViewPager (PageAdapter) :

```
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = IntroFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.intro_title_screen_1),
                            getString(R.string.intro_desc_screen_1));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = IntroFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.intro_title_screen_2),
                            getString(R.string.intro_desc_screen_2));
                    break;
                case 2:
...
```

In my PageTransformer, I want to do a translation on X for the title and for the description, but the behavior with this code is crazy:

```
mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
                int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

                if (position <= -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                    // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1] 

                    TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
                    textview.setTranslationX((float) (-(1 - position) * 1.2 * pageWidth));

                    textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    textview.setTranslationX((float) (-(1 - position) * 1.2 * pageWidth));

                } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                    // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                }
            }
        });
```

Is it possible to use a generic fragment like that and to use a PageTransformer on a specific widget inside (like in my case Title and Description textview) ?

I just want to do an X translation faster (on the right or on the left depends the slide way) on title and description textview.

Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to do an X translation faster (on the right or on the left
>   depends the slide way) on title and description textview.

yes it is possible. `position` is grater than zero when you move on the right, and smaller than zero when you move on the left. In your code the *velocity factor* is hardcoded (`1.2`). You have to find a mathematical function or a sets of values that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this indication. But is it possible to do find a view by id with the same id in these 5 fragments ? Because I use the same fragment 5 times to populate my ViewPager.

Comment: the view you get as parameter is the same view you return in onCreateView,